# .htaccess redirect url with parameters in a new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect my old link(deleted) in my new link with a .htaccess file,
for example,

```
From: http://www.example.com/page.php?value=2 (deleted)
To: http://www.example.com/detail.php?d=150
```

I tried with this but don't work. Becouse the file (page.php) does not exist, then the server give me 404 page not found.

My .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/page.php?value=2 http://www.example.it/detail.php?d=150 [END,R=301]
order deny,allow
```

Can you help me?

Comment: RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/page.php?value=2$ http://www.example.com/detail.php?d=150 [R=301,L]
try this

Answer (score 7):

[`RewriteRule` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewriterule) does not receive the entire url, but the part of URI relative to the directive your `htaccess` file is inside. Also, it doesn't receive the query parameters, you'll have to access them with the [`RewriteCond` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewritecond). So, it should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^value=2$
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /detail.php?d=150 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?value=2$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.it?page.php?d=150 [L,R]
```

This would redirect

- http://example.com/page.php?value=2

to

- http://example.it/detail.php?d=150

Reference : 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html